# Как устроены self, protected и private?

Tags: ооп, ruby, property

У меня возник вопрос с `self` и `protected`. Не могу понять, чем `protected` отличается от `private`, смотрел на англоязычных форумах, но всё равно ничего не понял, хотелось бы простенький пример.

Так же не могу понять, как работает `self`. Заметил, что иногда используется в методах.

Если быть конкретней, то вот увидел код по колбэкам и не понимаю, зачем тут `protected` и в методе `self`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :login, :email, presence: true
  before_validation :ensure_login_has_a_value
  protected
    def ensure_login_has_a_value
      if login.nil?
        self.login = email unless email.blank?
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Ты вот [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353272/private-vs-protected-visibility-good-practice-concern) тоже смотрел? Мне кажется, там написано все очень ясно.

Comment: @theoden, у меня технический английский хромает, мне и на русском иногда вещи, связанные с ООП трудно понимать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` - ссылка на объект, в контексте которого выполняется данный фрагмент кода.

```
class A
  def self.m # Здесь self - Объект(класс) A
  end

  def om
    self.class # Здесь self - Экземпляр класса A
  end
end
```

`protected` и `private` - методы экземпляра класса `Module`, определяющие область видимости.

`private` - говорит, о том, что метод может быть вызван только неявно(без указания имени экземпляра класса), и только из метода экземпляра класса и экземпляров потомков этого класса.

Пример:

```
class B
  def m
    n # так можно
    self.n # так нельзя 
    B.new.n # тоже нельзя    
  end

  private

  def n
  end
end
B.new.n # Так нельзя
```

`protected`-методы могут быть вызваны явно с указанием либо `self`, либо имени экземпляра класса. НО вызов этот должен происходить из метода экземпляра класса, в котором определен `protected`-метод, либо из методов экземпляров потомков этого класса.

```
class B
  def m
    n # так можно
    self.n # можно
    B.new.n # тоже можно
  end

  protected

  def n
  end
end
B.new.n # Так нельзя
```

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответ МАХОРКИ.

Часто `self` в присваивании просто используется для того, чтобы вызвать присваивающий метод, в котором часто бывает определены дополнительные действия кроме собственно присваивания, а не задать значение локальной переменной. Например есть класс `А`:

```
class A
   attr_reader :login

   def login= login
      @login = login
      # some code execution
   end

   def a value
      login = value
      self
   end

   def b value
      self.login = value
      self
   end
end

A.new.a(0).login # => nil
A.new.b(0).login # => 0
```

Так в методе `a` мы просто устанавливаем локальную переменную, а в `b` - переменную класса, вызвав метод присваивания.